# Acessando recursos com spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, multiple-file-upload

Olá.

Estou com alguns problemas ao recuperar uma imagem em uma pasta do meu projeto. Segue explicação básica do que estou tentando fazer: Em minha aplicação um formulário é submetido e junto dele uma imagem para cada item salvo.

Por questões de aprendizagem, eu salvo essa imagem dentro do meu banco de dados e quando precis o dela, faço a busca no banco e gravo em uma pasta dentro da aplicação, no meu caso 'resources/uploads' e mostro ela no HTML. O meu problema é que não estou conseguindo recuperar essa imagem no HTML quando salvo em qualquer outra pasta se não 'resources/static'.

Estou fazendo o mapeamento, mas mesmo assim não estou conseguindo. A imagem é gravada pelo back-end na pasta, porém quando tento mostrá-la recebo erro 404. Quando deixo ela dentro do resources/static consigo acessar normalmente, porém ao atualizar o cadastro que inclui a imagem, essa só é atualizada na visualização após reiniciar o servidor, apesar de aparecer na pasta de forma atualizada.

Enfim, a dúvida principal é:  Estou fazendo o mapeamento de forma correta? Se sim, como buscar essa imagem e mostrá-la dentro do HTML de forma a conseguir visualizá-la de forma atualizada?.

Estou utilizando spring e thymeleaf.

Linha do HTML com thymeleaf em que tento encontrar a imagem:

```
<img th:src="@{'/uploads/'+${animal.idAnimal}}" class="card-img-top" alt="Foto do animal"/>
```

Mapeamento do recurso:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/uploads/**").addResourceLocations("/uploads/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente desta forma:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                 .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```